# Azure functions some times start multiple instances when dequeing

Tags: azure-functions

I have a fairly simple azure function with following setup:

```
{
  "queues": {
    "maxPollingInterval": 2000,
    "visibilityTimeout": "00:10:00",
    "maxDequeueCount": 3,
    "batchSize": 12,
    "newBatchThreshold": 6
  }
}
```

I noticed sometimes when the function fails, it dequeue's the message as expected, and then it retry to execute the function again. The problem is sometimes it starts two instances on the same message. Is this known behaviour? My function looks like below. Should I do something before throwing the exception?

```
[FunctionName("MoveCopyFilesFolders")]
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("xx", Connection = "StorageConnStr")]string jobIdStr, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"MoveCopyFilesFolders processed: {jobIdStr}");

    Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "service", "xx" }, { "jobid", jobIdStr } };
    KK.Common.Instrumentation.AILogger logger = new KK.Common.Instrumentation.AILogger(configuration.ApplicationInsightsKey, properties);

    try
    {
        logger.WriteTrace($"Start moving/copy files/folders for jobid: {jobIdStr}", SeverityLevel.Verbose); 

        var jobId = Int32.Parse(jobIdStr);

        var moveCopyRepo = new CopyMoveRepository(configuration.DBConnectionString);
        var appRegRepo = new AppRegistrationRepository(configuration.DBConnectionString);

        CopyOrMoveItemsService.Run(jobId, moveCopyRepo, appRegRepo, logger);
        logger.WriteTrace("End move/copy files for site", SeverityLevel.Information);
        logger.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Info(ex.Message);
        logger.WriteException(ex);
        logger.Flush();
        throw ex;
    }          
}
```

The behaviour I see is the function starts as expected with only one instance. When failing sometimes two instances are started on the same message. I can see that because I have added 10 messages with different id as input, and after a failure two instances are running with same id.

Comment: Does the function actually run twice or is it only the logging that makes it appear twice? Where you retrieve the information that it runs twice from?

Comment: I have both logging and data in a database that both reflects the job runs twice.

Comment: What the code does is it moves a file. When the file is moved it marks in the database that file is moved. And I can see in application insights the function app is restarted, then the message is dequeued. And when it wakes up it starts two instances.